# IOS read text from MS Word

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ms-word

I am trying to read text from MS Word documents (.doc, .docx, .docs). I have been search from last day, but haven't found any solution for this. Please any one tell me what should i do? I have already tried UIWebview to get text from javascript this isn't working as well.

```
- (NSString *)textFromWordDocument:(NSString *)path {
    UIWebView *theWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theWebView loadRequest:request ];
    NSString *document = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText"];
    [theWebView release];
    return document;
}
```

If some one can tell me what should i do or where to look around, That will be really help full to me thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loading the UIWebView and then immediately trying to access the dom, its probably not yet ready.

Don't call stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: until UIWebViewDelegate didFinishLoad: has been called.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I was also thinking of this but wasn't sure about this. Working perfectly Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The code below saves a Word .docx file to the app's document directory at launch.
It then reads that file into a UIWebView during your viewDidLoad.
Finally, it waits for the UIWebView to load the document before fetching the text from the UIWebView.
Don't forget to conform to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol in your view controller's header file. And of course, the Word document must be included in your project. Make sure to add the document to Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /* WRITE WORD FILE TO DOCUMENT DIRECTORY */
    NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Text.docx"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/Text.docx"]];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   /* READ WORD FILE FROM DOCUMENT DIRECTORY TO WEB VIEW */
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *wordFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Text.docx"];
    UIWebView *theWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    NSURL *wordFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:wordFilePath];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:wordFileUrl];
    [theWebView loadRequest:request];
    theWebView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:theWebView];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    /* GET TEXT FROM WEB VIEW */
    NSString *text = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText"];
}
```